# hangman console game in c

Tags: c, linked-list

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct dic {
    int index;
    char string[10];
    struct dic *next;
}node;
main() {
    FILE *fp;int indexrand;node *head;node *mainhead;
    char s[10],question[10],answer[10];char check;
    int count=-1,i,j,k,len,flag;head=(node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
    mainhead=head;
    fp=fopen("dictionary.txt","r");
    while((fgets(s,10,fp))!=NULL) {
        strcpy(head->string,s);
        count++;  
        (head->index)=count;
        head->next=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        head=head->next;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    head->next=NULL;
    srand(time(NULL));
    indexrand=rand()%(count+1);
    printf("%d\n",indexrand);
    for(head=mainhead;(head->next)!=NULL;head=head->next)
        if((head->index)==indexrand)
            strcpy(question,(head->string));
    printf("%s\n",question);
    len=strlen(question);
    printf("%d\n",len);
    for(i=0;i<len-1;i++)
        answer[i]='_';
    answer[i]='\0';
    printf("%s\n",answer);
    printf("6 chances to go\n");
    for(i=0,k=6;k>0;i++) { 
        flag=0;
        printf("%d\n",i);
        scanf("%c",&check);
        for(j=0;j<(len-1);j++) {
            if(question[j]==check) {
                flag++;
                answer[j]=check;
            }
        }  
        if(flag>0)
            printf("%d chances to go\n",k);
        if(flag==0) { 
            k--;
            printf("no common letters...%d chances to go\n",k);
        }
        printf("%s\n",answer);
    } 
}
```

The file dictionary.txt has only one word per line.

While running the code, for every attempt from the user (i.e after user enters a character) the statement `no common letters...%d chances to go\n",k` is being displayed even if the `flag > 0` condition is satisfied.

How do I correct this?

Comment: use better variable names. flag, i and k don't tell me anything.

Comment: In order to get better answers you should improve the title to your question and edit the body of your question for legibility. As it stands your title is not very helpful, it should contain a brief description of the problem.

Comment: Don't run all your declarations together like that.  Add some comments.

Comment: This kind of looks like a first draft of a code golf lol

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
 scanf("%c",&check);
```

is reading characters the user types, *including the newline*.

You probably just want to read the first character on the line: use fgets() to read the whole line, and then set `check = line[0]`.

Comment: ... or simply ignore any non-alphabetic characters (using `isalpha`)

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%d\n",i);
scanf("%c",&check);
```

Because of these statements,scanf is taking \n as a parameter and so printing "no common letters..." every time.Replace the above code with

```
printf("%d",i);
scanf("\n%c",&check);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to pass a string to scanf, so try it :

scanf("%s",&check);

Comment: Except `check` is just a char, not a char array, so there isn't space for more than a single character.